# Как скопировать snap приложение целиком на другой пк ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu

я хочу скопировать ряд приложений, одно из них telegram на несколько своих ПК с аналогичными ОС ubuntu 20.04 , как это сделать? На примере телеграм может кто то подсказать?
Все приложения из пакетов snap

Comment: Чё-то типа `snap save`?

Comment: не могу найти нечего в гугле, можно какую нибудь инфу?

Comment: разобрался как делать save, но как восстановить? Снапшот лежит в папке /var/lib/snapd/snapshots/

Comment: Ну наверное `restore`? Если по логике.